# Reporting Services: freezing rows in tables

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I'm a bit new to Reporting Services 2005. I have a report that gets emailed out and some users want to freeze the top two rows while scrolling. Is this possible?

Comment: hi ken , is it worked for you ?

Comment: hi ken, can you accept answer if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

set  your fixheader property true

for this `Select Table > property > fixheader = true`

Second way open your rdlc file in xml edition

put the fix header as show below in your header tags

```
<header>
  <FixedHeader>true</FixedHeader>
</Header>
```